# OpenCv Manager Package was not found

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I want to work with OpenCV in my android application. I'm using Android Studio 4.0.1 and OpenCV 4.5
Everything is ok but when I install the application on my device I got the following error:

OpenCV Manager Package was not found.

when I install OpenCV manager I got the following error:

OpenCV was not initialized correctly

please help me. I have tested all solution on the internet but still problem not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a static initialization to include all OpenCV binaries in the apk?

Follow this doc: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization

Comment: i have heared static initialization is bad for production purpose. There is no other way?